# Missing Achievement in Fruit Ninja

Tags: achievements, fruit-ninja

I played FN on my WP7 in trial mode and cut over 150 fruits but I didn't get the achievement because I was in trial.  When I bought the game, it 'skipped' over the achievement.  I have all the other fruit count achievements but not the 150.

How do I get the game to recognize that I have passed it and give me that achievement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there was a similar question to this lately, but I can't find it currently.

Anyway, the way the game works, it only increments the achievement counter forward. However, the developers didn't consider this when implementing the achievements, as the counter is only checked once -- people who bought the game before the achievements were implemented are in a similar boat, unable to trigger any of the totals they have long since passed.

Unless the developers patch in a fix, there's no way to achieve it with your current game file.

Comment: Based on what you said, I wondered if uninstalling and reinstallng would reset the counters.  Well it did work and I was able to quickly get my achievement.  Of course the major problem with this was ALL my other stats etc. were reset as well.  I basically had to start all over again.  At least I have my achievement.

Comment: Good to know! Glad I could be of help.